# Increase efficiency of object counting with bwlabel/bwconncomp in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to count objects in an image in MATLAB. I am checking the image against certain values with a for loop, and any pixel with this value turns white (background is black).

```
for J = 1:n
    currentImageEqualsJ = 255*(originalImage == i);
    [~,num] = bwlabel(currentImageEqualsJ, 8);
    results_Array(J) = num;
end
```

This takes a long time, though, and I heard that speed can be improved by vectorizing the operations. However, I am am unsure as to how to turn this into a series of matrix operations.

I have tried using bwconncomp (which ended up being slower than bwlabel). I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: ....comparing `originalImage` against imaginary unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to compare every scale level at the same time.

```
Img = randi(255,100,100);
CC = arrayfun(@(x) bwconncomp(bsxfun(@eq,Img,x)), 0:255);
Count = [CC.NumObjects];
bar(Count)
```

[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) is used to replace the slower `Img==x` operation.

If you don't need the result of `bwconncomp` except the number of objects, you can combine `CC` and `Count` into one line, using [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html)

```
Count = arrayfun(@(x) subsref(bwconncomp(bsxfun(@eq,Img,x)), ...
    struct('type', '.', 'subs', 'NumObjects')), 0:255);
```

Comment: Awesome! Lot faster than a for loop (even parfor w/ 8 workers)! Thanks!